# Wait for rotation animation to finish in android before opening new activity?

Tags: java, android, animation, rotation

My code is as follows:

```
connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            pointer.animate().rotation(connectButtonAngle - 45).start();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

How would I get it to wait for the pointer to finish spinning before starting the next activity?

Answer (score 3):

Change your implementation to this, and you will get when Animation ends.

```
connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
       pointer.animate().rotation(connectButtonAngle - 45).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        }).start();


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this code:**

```
pointer.animate()
    .rotation(connectButtonAngle - 45)
    .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreenActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
      }
    })
    .start();
```